# Finding solution set of rational equations with constants

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having a difficult time finding the solution of the following rational equation for all $a,b \in \!R$

$$\frac{ax-1}{x-b}=2$$

I am told this equation will be solved in different cases, but I cannot seem to find all of these different cases. I have tried to draw a tree with different branches corresponding to different condition.

I cannot draw the tree diagram here, but the first step I've recognized is to assume $b \neq x $ and find that $ax-1=2(x-b)$. But I cannot seem to coherently find all cases after this.

I would be grateful for guidance on solving this equation since I cannot solve it myself or find any resources dealing with this kind of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

multiplying by $$x-b\ne 0$$ we get
$$ax-1=2x-2b$$ isolating $x$
$$x(a-2)=1-2b$$
now we say if $$a-2=0$$ and $$1-2b\neq 0$$ then we obtain no Solutions.
if $$a-2=0$$ and $$1-2b=0$$ then there are infinity Solutions.
if $a\ne 2$ then we have $$x=\frac{1-2b}{a-2}$$

Comment: (+1) not only are there an infinite number of solutions when $a=2$ and $b=\frac12$, but any $x\ne\frac12$ is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, if you assume $b\neq x$ then you get $ax-1=2(x-b)$, in which case you can solve for x 
\begin{equation}
x=\frac{2b-1}{2-a}.
\end{equation}
Here you must assume that $a\neq 2$.  If $a=2$, then the equation has no solutions unless $b=\frac{1}{2}$, in which case the equation is true for all $x$ (to see this plug in the values in the original equation and divide both sides by two).

Now consider the case where $b=x$.  In this case, you are dividing by $0$, so clearly the equation is not true unless the numerator is zero, in which case $a=1/b$.  You could say that $0/0$ is undefined, but you could also consider the limit (I am assuming a and b are constant here)
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\rightarrow b}\frac{\frac{1}{b}x-1}{x-b}.
\end{equation}
This limit can be computed using L'Hopital's rule, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule to be 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\rightarrow b}\frac{\frac{1}{b}x-1}{x-b}=\frac{1}{b}.
\end{equation}
So in this case, the solution would only be true if $b=\frac{1}{2}$.  This is precisely the case considered previously, where all values of $x$ are solutions, but in this case we have chosen exactly the $x$ which makes both the numerator and denominator vanish.  I think technically this would not be considered a solution.

If you were dealing with projective geometry, you might even get a solution if $a=2$ and $b\neq\frac{1}{2}$, because in this context parallel lines meet ``at infinity''.  However, I'm assuming you are not interested in this case.

Comment: limits and l'hopitals rules for pre-calculus?

Comment: I was just answering the question bro

Comment: Not really. $f(x); x = b$ is not the same thing as $\lim_{x\to b} f(x)$ So that's not actually an answer.  $\frac {ab-1}{b-b} \ne 2$.  Ever. ... well, assuming we are dealing with real numbers....

Comment: As stated in the solution I wrote.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac {ax - 1}{x-b} = 2$.

We can assume that $x-b \ne 0$ otherwise that statement is certainly not true as $\frac {anything}0$ is undefined and can not equal $2$.

So we can multiply both sides by $x - b$.

$\frac {ax-1}{x-b}(x-b) = 2(x - b)$

$ax - 1 = 2x -2b$

Add and subtract things to both sides to have the variable $x$ on one side and constants on the other.

$ax - 2x - 1 = 2x - 2x -2b$

$(a - 2)x - 1 = - 2b$

$(a -2)x -1 +1 = - 2b + 1$

$(a-2)x = 1 - 2b$.

Now we want to divide both sides by $a-2$ but that would assume $a-2 \ne 0$.  We must consider what happens if $a-2 = 0$.

If $a -2 \ne 0$ then

$(a-2)x\frac 1{a-2} = \frac {1-2b}{a-2}$

$x = \frac {1-2b}{a-2}$.

And that's that.  So for example if $a = 5; b= 3$ then $x = \frac {1-2*3}{5-2} = -\frac 53$.  This will hold for *any* $a,b$ *assuming* that $a - 2 \ne 0$>

However if $a-2 =0$

Then $a = 2$

And $(a -2)x = 1 -2b$

$0*x = 1-2b$

$0 = 1 -2b$

$2b = 1 - 2b + 2b$

$2b= 1$.

$2b\frac 12 = 1\frac 12$

$b = \frac 12$

If $a = 2$ then $b$ *must* equal $\frac 12$ and $x$ can be any value at all *except* $\frac 12$.

Ex.

$\frac {2x -1}{x - 1/2} = 2$.  $x $ can not be $\frac 12$ but if $x$ is $5,237$ then

$\frac {2*5237 - 1}{5237 - \frac 12} =$

$\frac {10,473}{5236.5} = 2$.